# LEFT OUTER JOIN EQUIVALENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, equivalent

I have a tables contains null values. In ORDER table i have 2 null in PART_ID section and 2 null values in CUSTOMER_ID.

And i have that kind of query:

```
SELECT O.ORDER_ID , O.ORDER_DATE , O.CUST_ID, O.QUANTITY ,O.PART_ID ,
       C.CUST_NAME, C.CUST_CODE, P.PART_NAME, P.PART_CODE
FROM [ORDER] O
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PART P ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
```

So here is my question. How can i do it without using outer join ? 
I tried too many things including where not exists or this ;

```
SELECT *
FROM [ORDER] O ,CUSTOMER C, PART P
WHERE C.CUST_ID = (
  SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE O.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
) AND P.PART_ID = (SELECT PART_ID FROM PART P WHERE O.PART_ID = P.PART_ID)
```

but i couldn't find solution. If there is a solution how it will be ?

(Note: this is homework.)

I have that kind of table :

[image]

and left outer join gives that :

[image]

the hw said do it without using outer join and get same table as left outer join gives.  But like a said i coulnd't. I'm also using MSSQL.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Curious to know why, given the syntax is deprecated, and [discouraged by static analysis tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Also the `OUTER` in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is implied. You can just write `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: I think @Yuck 's comment is the answer for your question

Comment: @MarkBannister is that SO policy to require to explain why the question is asked? This question looks pretty clear to me without giving any more background.

Comment: @Yuck I want to do this because its told me like that. They made me to do without using outer joins. They told me i can do it with simple select and inner join and nested query. I m trying to figure it out but i couldn't.

Comment: @developerCoder: Who are "they", and why are "they" telling you how to write a query? Is this homework?

Comment: @MarkBAnnister  Yes its homework and im trying to find out for 4 days but i couldnt.

Comment: @developerCoder: OK, downvote removed.

Comment: God bless you, what a stupid assignment. I'll never understand why instructors *force* their students to do work (IMHO) **the wrong way**.

Comment: @Yuck I think they force us to think different to improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outer join produces super-set over inner join. Indeed, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join): *A left outer join returns all the values from an inner join plus all values in the left table that do not match to the right table.*

So to model left outer join using inner join one could use *UNION* of inner join *SELECT* between same tables with same join condition and another *SELECT* from 1st table that returns all rows without a match from the right table (I reduced your case to a single left join):

```
SELECT O.ORDER_ID , O.ORDER_DATE , O.CUST_ID, O.QUANTITY ,O.PART_ID ,
       P.PART_NAME, P.PART_CODE
FROM [ORDER] O JOIN PART P ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
UNION
SELECT O.ORDER_ID , O.ORDER_DATE , O.CUST_ID, O.QUANTITY ,O.PART_ID ,
       NULL, NULL 
FROM [ORDER] O
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'found' FROM PART P WHERE P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID)
```

Comment: @topchef Yes its right but it didn't give CUST_NAME and CUST_CODE how can i add them too ?

Comment: that would be the rest of your homework then: just follow same approach - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want to get matches to the columns with NULL values, instead of having them fail.  If so, just modify the join conditions:

```
FROM [ORDER] O
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PART P
     ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID or (p.Part_id is NULL and o.Part_id is null)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER C
     ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID or (c.cust_id is null and o.cust_id is null)
```

The major issue with this approach is that many (most?) SQL engines will not use indexes for the join.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use outer join? Isn't this the result you want? :

```
FROM [ORDER] O 
LEFT JOIN PART P 
ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID and P.PARTID is not null
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER C 
ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID and C.CUSTID is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

So complete answer should be like this (after my teacher gave results) :

```
 SELECT O.ORDER_ID,O.ORDER_DATE,O.CUST_ID,
(SELECT C.CUST_CODE FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.CUST_ID=O.CUST_ID) AS CUST_CODE,
(SELECT C.CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.CUST_ID=O.CUST_ID) AS CUST_NAME,
O.PART_ID,
(SELECT P.PART_CODE FROM PART P WHERE P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID ) AS PART_CODE,
(SELECT P.PART_NAME FROM PART P WHERE P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID ) AS PART_NAME,
O.QUANTITY

FROM [ORDER] O
```