# Syntax error. in query (MS Access sql)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS access query which I am running in my c sharp application, I am able to run the query fine using SSMS (I know this isn't an access sql but its all I can use) and when I import it into my c sharp application I get an incorrect syntax error. (My c sharp application reads from access dbf files) Here is the full sql below:

```
SELECT ([T2_BRA].[REF] + [F7]) AS NewStyle,
            Sum(T2_BRA.Q11) AS QTY1, Sum(T2_BRA.Q12) AS QTY2, 
                Sum(T2_BRA.Q13) AS QTY3, Sum(T2_BRA.Q14) AS QTY4, Sum(T2_BRA.Q15) AS QTY5, Sum(T2_BRA.Q16) AS QTY6, Sum(T2_BRA.Q17) AS QTY7, Sum(T2_BRA.Q18) AS QTY8, 
                    Sum(T2_BRA.Q19) AS QTY9, Sum(T2_BRA.Q20) AS QTY10, Sum(T2_BRA.Q21) AS QTY11, Sum(T2_BRA.Q22) AS QTY12, Sum(T2_BRA.Q23) AS QTY13, T2_HEAD.REF,
                        Sum(T2_BRA.LY11) AS LY1, Sum(T2_BRA.LY12) AS LY2, Sum(T2_BRA.LY13) AS LY3, Sum(T2_BRA.LY14) AS LY4, Sum(T2_BRA.LY15) AS LY5, 
                            Sum(T2_BRA.LY16) AS LY6, Sum(T2_BRA.LY17) AS LY7, Sum(T2_BRA.LY18) AS LY8, Sum(T2_BRA.LY19) AS LY9, Sum(T2_BRA.LY20) AS LY10,
                                Sum(T2_BRA.LY21) AS LY11, Sum(T2_BRA.LY22) AS LY12, Sum(T2_BRA.LY23) AS LY13, T2_BRA.BRANCH, T2_HEAD.LASTDELV, T2_EAN.EAN_CODE, T2_SIZES.S01 AS S1, 
                                T2_SIZES.S02 AS S2, 
                                T2_SIZES.S03 AS S3, 
                                T2_SIZES.S04 AS S4, 
                                T2_SIZES.S05 AS S5, 
                                T2_SIZES.S06 AS S6, 
                                T2_SIZES.S07 AS S7, 
                                T2_SIZES.S08 AS S8, 
                                T2_SIZES.S09 AS S9, 
                                T2_SIZES.S10 AS S10, 
                                T2_SIZES.S11 AS S11, 
                                T2_SIZES.S12 AS S12, 
                                T2_SIZES.S13 AS S13 
                                    FROM ((((((T2_BRA INNER JOIN T2_HEAD ON T2_BRA.REF = T2_HEAD.REF)) INNER JOIN T2_SIZES ON T2_HEAD.SIZERANGE = T2_SIZES.SIZERANGE) INNER JOIN 
                                    (SELECT Right(T2_LOOK.[KEY],3) AS NewCol, T2_LOOK.F1 AS MasterColour, Left(T2_LOOK.[KEY],3) AS Col, T2_LOOK.F7
                                FROM T2_LOOK
                                WHERE (Left(T2_LOOK.[KEY],3))='COL') as Colour ON T2_BRA.COLOUR = Colour.NewCol) LEFT JOIN T2_EAN ON T2_EAN.T2T_CODE LIKE (SELECT ('#' + ([T2_BRA].[REF] + [F7]) + '#'))))
                                    WHERE [T2_BRA].[REF] = '010403' AND T2_BRA.BRANCH in ('A','G')
                                    GROUP BY ([T2_BRA].[REF] + [F7]),T2_HEAD.REF, T2_BRA.BRANCH, T2_HEAD.LASTDELV, T2_EAN.EAN_CODE, T2_SIZES.S01, 
T2_SIZES.S02, T2_SIZES.S03, T2_SIZES.S04, T2_SIZES.S05, T2_SIZES.S06, T2_SIZES.S07, T2_SIZES.S08, T2_SIZES.S09, T2_SIZES.S10, T2_SIZES.S11, T2_SIZES.S12, T2_SIZES.S13
```

The line I am getting the syntax error is:

```
LEFT JOIN T2_EAN ON T2_EAN.T2T_CODE LIKE (SELECT ('#' + ([T2_BRA].[REF] + [F7]) + '#')
```

Any help would be great! :)

Comment: Your brackets seems out of line and the `SELECT` clause you've pointed out doesn't have a `FROM` clause to go with it.  I can't put my finger exactly what's wrong.  I'd consider changing the `+` to an `&` as that is how Access prefers it (`1+1=2` while `1 & 1 = 11`).  Not sure though as you're using SSMS & C#.

Comment: Is [T2_BRA].[REF] a date? SQL uses "%" for the like query. For example, if I wanted to look for the word "data" anywhere in the string, I would use: `WHERE [Column] LIKE '%data%' `

Comment: As an example the first join in your `FROM` clause has these brackets `((T2_BRA INNER JOIN T2_HEAD ON T2_BRA.REF = T2_HEAD.REF))` - there's no need to place two sets of brackets around the join, just one will do in this instance.

Comment: @ErinB.  Would the SQL get translated using SQL Server or Access?  For Access the wildcard is `*` rather than `%`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook ... that depends. In ODBC mode, Access uses ANSI-92's `%` but in GUI .exe mode uses ANSI-89's `*` wildcard operator. See more [info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1)

Comment: I misread the original - if you're connecting to Access data, use the * character. In your query, you're using '#'. What are the values for these fields? `('#' + ([T2_BRA].[REF] + [F7]) + '#')`

Comment: Hey guys, I have tried using all the wildcard symbols *, # and ?, still getting the error, also I removed any unused brackets and it is the same problem :(

Comment: # is a valid wildcard in MS Access and is used, combined with the LIKE operator,  to prompt the user for a pattern to search ([Doc here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897(v=office.12).aspx)). However I don't think that doing a `LIKE <nested query result>` is allowed and this is probably the root cause here.  All in one, it is certainly completely false to prompt the user for a pattern to search on  a nested query result.

Comment: I would save the nested query result in a variable and use that value within the query to see if that's where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem `JOIN` clause has some issues for the MS Access dialect:

1. `SELECT` that uses a column and table reference must have `FROM` source;
2. String concatenation does not use `+` but `&` operator;
3. `LIKE` expressions can be used in `ON` clauses but the comparison will be row by row (not searching values across all rows of joining table as possibly intended).

Correcting above still imposes a challenge since you are attempting to join a table by the `LIKE` expression in a `LEFT JOIN` relationship.

Consider first comma-separating your table, *T2_EAN*, which equates to a cross join then add a `WHERE` clause running an `EXISTS` subquery. Doing so, `WHERE` becomes the implicit join and *T2_EAN* column will point to field in main query. Do be aware other tables in query must use `INNER JOIN` for this comma-separated table. And adjust parentheses with removal of `LEFT JOIN`.

```
FROM T2_EAN, (((((
...
WHERE [T2_BRA].[REF] = '010403' AND T2_BRA.BRANCH in ('A','G') 
  AND EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM [T2_BRA] t 
   WHERE T2_EAN.T2T_CODE LIKE ('%' & (t.[REF] & t.[F7]) & '%')
```

Now, the challenge here is the `WHERE` will correspond to an `INNER JOIN` and not `LEFT JOIN`. To overcome this, consider adding a `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) query exactly the same as above but without the `EXISTS` subquery. This will then return records that did not meet `LIKE` criteria and `UNION` will leave out duplicates. See [LEFT JOIN Equivalent here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573140/1422451). Be sure to add a `NULL` to `SELECT` wherever *T2_EAN* column was referenced:

```
SELECT ... T2_HEAD.LASTDELV, T2_EAN.EAN_CODE, T2_SIZES.S01 AS S1 ...

UNION

SELECT ... T2_HEAD.LASTDELV, NULL AS EAN_CODE, T2_SIZES.S01 AS S1 ...
```

---

Do note: performance is not guaranteed with this adjustment. Further considerations include:

1. Once query compiles and runs, be sure to save this large query or view as a stored object in the MS Access database and not as a scripted C# string query. Even if you do not have MS Access GUI .exe, you can save queries via code using MS Access' [querydefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) object with VBA (i.e., Excel VBA) or [COM-interface with C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317114/how-to-automate-microsoft-access-by-using-visual-c0) or any other language that supports COM like open-source Python, PHP, R.

   Then have C# app simply retrieve the view for its purposes: `SELECT * FROM mySavedQuery`. Stored queries tend to be more efficient especially for many joins and complex queries than coded queries since the Access engine saves best execution plan and caches stats.
2. Remove the need of `LIKE` by saving matching values without extraneous other characters so `=` can be used as I believe MS Access's `LIKE` will not use indexes in query plans.
3. Upsize your Access database to SQL Server for more sophisticated handling with the T-SQL dialect. SQL Server has easy facilities in SSMS to import Access .mdb/.accdb files.

Answer (score 0):

You LEFT OUTER JOIN's `ON` clause makes no sense:

```
LEFT JOIN T2_EAN ON T2_EAN.T2T_CODE LIKE (SELECT ('#' + ([T2_BRA].[REF] + [F7]) + '#')
```

You need to join `T2_EAN` to your values in ALREADY PRESENT `T2_BRA` table in your FROM clause. By sticking `T2_BRA` into a subquery here you are bringing the table in twice, which is nonsense. It's also not allowed to use a subquery inside a `LIKE` condition.

If it were allowed and did make sense, you would end up with a cartesian product between all the intermediate result set from those inner joins and your left outer join'd table, which is almost definitely not what you are after.

Instead (probably something like):

```
LEFT JOIN T2_EAN ON T2_EAN.T2T_CODE LIKE '#' + [T2_BRA].[REF] + [F7] + '#'
```

This is now saying "Left outer join `t2_ean` to `T2_Bra` where the `T2T_Code` matches the concatenation of `<any one digit> + T2_Bra.Ref + F7 + <any one digit>`" Without knowing your data, I cant' vouch for that being the thing you want, but it feels like the closest interpretation when reverse engineering your incorrect query.

You mention in a comment "I have tried using all the wildcard symbols *, # and ?" Don't just try wildcard symbols hoping something will work. They each do something VERY different. Use the one that you need for you situation. [Decent explanation of the three wildcards that work with the `LIKE` operator in access here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php). You may want to switch to the asterisk while debugging (since it's the most wide open of the wild cards) and then once you are getting reasonable results, use the much tighter `#` (match only one digit) operator.