# How can I create a left join using cross join in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, cross-join

How can I create a query equivalent to a left join without actually using left join in SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate a left join without using "left join"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159729/simulate-a-left-join-without-using-left-join)

Comment: INNER JOIN UNION ALL missing rows.

Comment: Why would you want to? Do you mean without actually writing "Left join" or that the query plan is without a left join?

Comment: Your title & body differ. What is your question? What are definitions of left join & cross join that you understand? What are you able to do? Also, this is a faq, so why did other questions not help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN EQUIVALENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572333/left-outer-join-equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do it with `cross join`.  You *can* do it with an `inner join` and `union all`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     b 
     on . . .
union all
select a.*, . . .  -- manually put in b columns
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where . . . );  -- join conditions in the `where` clause
```